# Param Url to view Django

Tags: django

I have an URL with a parameter session:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('session/<str:sessions>', photographies.views.session, name='session'), #añadido 
]
```

And what I want to do is to filter some pictures with a common session name into the db

```
 <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/session/{{photography.session}}">
```

So I try already making query to the db using .get() and also trying to pass the param direct into the view using new_session and then filter inside the view whit a simple if, the problem, it doest work, when I compare the photography.session == sessions nothing happen and when i print {{sessions}} it print in the view but like this: ('param',)

```
def session(request, sessions): #añadido
    new_session = sessions,
    photographies = Photography_session.objects.get(session=sessions) #añadido
    print(new_session)
    return render(request, 'photographies/session.html', {
        'photographies':photographies,
        'new_session': new_session
        }) #añadido
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *filter*, since it is possible that there are no `Photography_session` objects for the given `sessions` variable, or multiple ones:

```
def session(request, sessions): #añadido
    photographies = Photography_session.objects.filter(session=sessions)
    return render(request, 'photographies/session.html', {
        'photographies':photographies,
        'new_session': sessions
    })
```